# Should I Have a div with the Width of 100% When the Content Forces Horizontal Scrolling?

Tags: html, css, width

I have a webpage where I have a header section and then some content.  In the content, I have a grid and some of the views show many columns which (depending on the screen size) will create a horizontal scroll bar on the browser)

my html looks like sort of like this:

```
 <head></head>
 <body>
      <div id="TopHeader"></div>
      <div id="MainContent"></div>
 </body>
```

so often the **content that is inside of "MainContent" is wider than the screen** .  Right now I have my css for my div like this:

```
 #TopHeader {
    background-color: black;
}
```

but when I scroll over to the right, the background of this section is white.  I tried to solve this by doing this:

```
#TopHeader {
min-width:1150px;
    background-color: black;
 }
```

which helps a little bit but this is a hard coded solution and if the width happens to be > 1150px, I run into the same problem.

The only other thing I can think of is to put TopHeader inside of main (which will fix this). something like this:

```
 <head></head>
 <body>
      <div id="MainContent">
            <div id="TopHeader"></div>
       </div>
 </body>
```

**but** the issue there is that I want padding around my content (what was the MainContent section and I don't want this padding around the top header so that doesn't seem to work.  If i create a new div like this

```
 <head></head>
 <body>
      <div id="MainContent">
            <div id="TopHeader"></div>
            <div id="InnerMainForPadding"></div>
       </div>
 </body>
```

I am back to the original problem listed above.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: If you want a div to be the full width of a page its width should be set to 100%; Also can you provide a link? Or maybe an example of the layout you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about having the scroll bar on the content wrapper instead of the browser window?

```
#MainContent {
    overflow: auto;
}
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/SUfkh/2/show/

Comment: I see where you are going with this and initially I thought this was the perfect solution but I see one blocker.  If the content loaded is very tall, you don't actually see the horizontal scroll bar so that is confusing because you are looking to scroll horizontally but there is no scroll bar unless you scroll all of the way down . .

Comment: @leora You could make it work with absolute positioning: http://jsfiddle.net/SUfkh/3/show/

Comment: good idea .. i think this is a winner . . not what I was originally thinking but it definitely solves my problem

Answer (score 2):

Change it to:

```
html, body, #TopHeader { 
    background-color: black; 
}
```